Ubuntu 24.04 started receiving activation of network connection failed
I've been trying to sort this myself, but I am now stuck.
I've rebooted my router
Windows dual boot on same drive. The machine works OK, as well as all other devices in the household work OK.
This is a few days old completely fresh install of Ubuntu which has been been working OK up until a few hours ago (10th Sept 24 AM).
Wireless GitHub Info Output: https://termbin.com/0xoh
Results of sudo lshw -C network :
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 1c:b7:2c:a3:ab:e1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2104000-b2104fff memory:b2100000-b2103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:c2:dd:8c:29:87
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:56 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2000000-b2003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: enx7a4da4bc499d
       serial: 7a:4d:a4:bc:49:9d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.114.13 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

Results of dpkg -l wpasupplicant :
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version            Architecture Description
+++-==============-==================-============-==============================================
ii  wpasupplicant  2:2.10-21ubuntu0.1 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)

I've tried sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) and sudo reboot

SOLVED - In my case, I deleted /etc/resolv.conf using terminal
Open terminal
'sudo -i
cd /
cd etc
rm resolve.conf'
Reboot, internet came back

In my case, I deleted /etc/resolv.conf and rebooted using the terminal as follows.
sudo -i   
cd /etc   
rm resolv.conf  
sudo reboot  

Then the internet came back.

Hi all,
I observed the same issue again, this time the resolv/conf deletion and sudo reboot didnt solve it.
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
followed by
sudo reboot
resolved it again.

I had the same issue after the 24.04 upgrade. I noticed that the file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf had been created during the upgrade, which caused the problem. Removing this file (or backing it up to another location) and restarting NetworkManager service resolved my issue.
rm /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf
systemctl restart NetworkManager

